How can I simulate congestion on Devnet?
We've been having alot of issues due to congestion on Mainnet. However our dev environment is built around devnet where there is almost no congestion. Is there some way for us to simulate congestion on devnet for testing purposes and development?

It's not a great idea to simulate adversarial conditions on devnet, especially because it'll harm devs, but it could be possible to do it on testnet! At the local test validator level, you could add some code to randomly drop transactions or require a certain compute unit price, but it's a very tough problem to simulate for end users
